# Syntax Error in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-urls

What's causing the syntax error in this urls.py ?

It says

```
syntax error at Line 27[(r'^xd_receiver\.html$',.....] in ursl.py.
```

I can't figure out where the problem is.

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
        # Example:
        # (r'^universityDB/', include('universityDB.foo.urls')),

        # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
        # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
        (r'^registrationForm/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.registrationForm'),
        (r'^userDetails/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.userDetails'),
        (r'^login/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.login'),
        (r'^userCreated/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.userCreated'),
        (r'^forgotPassword/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.forgotPassword'),
        (r'^passwordRecovery/$','universityDB.universityDetails.views.passwordRecovery'),     
        (r'^accounts/profile', 'universityDB.universityDetails.views.profile'),   
        (r'^xd_receiver\.html$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'xd_receiver.html'}, name='xd_receiver'),   
        (r'^login_facebook_connect/$', 'login_facebook_connect', name='facebook_connect_ajax'),

    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to name your URLs, you must use the [`url(...)` function](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#url), i.e.

```
url(r'^xd_receiver\.html$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'xd_receiver.html'}, name='xd_receiver')
```

…rather than:

```
(r'^xd_receiver\.html$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'xd_receiver.html'}, name='xd_receiver')
```

Comment: one clarification there is no *force* or *must* to use `url()`. you can simply write `(r'^xd_receiver\.html$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'xd_receiver.html'}, 'xd_receiver')` which will work fine (using tuples)